# How to pass dynamic data to content_template method - Elementor widget development?

Tags: wordpress, widget, elementor

In a `render()` method of my widget class, I can easily query the posts data and render as below code and it shows up at frontend correctly.

```php
protected function render(){
 $args =  [
            'order'          => 'DESC',
            'posts_per_page' => 4
        ];

        $query = new \WP_Query($args);
        $posts = $query->posts;

        foreach($posts as $post) : ?>

             // loop the post here

        <?php endforeach; 
      
}
```

However, the posts doesn't show up in Elementor editor page.
I try to access posts data inside `content_template` method and it doesn't work.
So, how can I pass the posts data to `content_template` method and render it?

```php
protected function content_template(){
?>

      <# _.each( settings.posts, function( post ) { #>
          <!-- loop the post here -->
      <# } #>

<?php }
```

Answer (score 2):

I found your post, because I had the same problem this evening. The solution was ridiculous easy.

I removed my content_template() function. That's it.

The preview was then generated by the render() function. I don't have to use the loop, but I need other WordPress functions like get_the_excerpt(Id). This code runs in the preview as well.

```
protected function render() {
    $settings = $this->get_settings_for_display();

    if ( empty( $settings['post_id'] ) ) {
        return;
    }
    $excerpt = get_the_excerpt($settings['post_id']) ;
    $featuredImage = get_the_post_thumbnail($settings['post_id']) ;
    ?>
    <h3>
        <?php echo $settings['post_id']; ?>
    </h3>
    <div><?php echo $featuredImage ?></div>
    <div><?php echo $excerpt ?></div>
    <?php
}
```

I should have tested a loop as well, but it's really late, and if I don't answer now, I will never do.

Comment: `content_template()` is still there in their documentation, it's for rendering the interactive DOM elements. Suppose that you want to inline edit the title of a post or you want to preview slider is sliding or you want to click button and trigger something, you can't avoid using `content_template()`. Btw, your answer is helpful.

Comment: Of course, you are right. I looked up some widgets from a plugin, where a list of posts is printed. They solved the problem by omitting the content_template(). I'm not really happy with this workaround as long, as I find nothing in the documentation about leaving out the content_template().